# C# ASP.NET Ask user if it is duplicate if they would like to continue to Add the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, confirmation

Is there a way when the user clicks the add button on a modalpopup to check if this is a duplicate user and provide the user with a confirmation if they would like to continue to add the record?

This is a C# asp.net application.

All the add does currently is add the first and last name to the database.

Comment: You can check entered value with your database. but if you have done something then show us. it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `Membership` classes, you don't have to check manually. When you call [Membership.CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es.aspx), it will throw an exception if there's an existing user (as well as other errors).

```
try
{
    Membership.CreateUser(...);
}
catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)    
{
    if(e.StatusCode == MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName)
    {
        //user already exists
    }
}
```

You can see all the values of the `MembershipCreateStatus` enum [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipcreatestatus.aspx).